# check unique values in multiple colums between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I am trying to check multiple colums in two tables to see if any of the rows between the tables doenst match up. This is what I have right now for only 1 colum:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM   {table1} 
        FULL OUTER JOIN {table2} 
        ON table1.colum1 = table2.colum1
        WHERE table1.colum1 IS NULL
        OR table2.colum1 IS NULL
```

and this is what i tried for 2 colums:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM   {table1} 
        FULL OUTER JOIN {table2} 
        ON table1.colum1 = table2.colum1 and table1.colum2 = table2.colum2
        WHERE table1.colum1 IS NULL and table1.colum
        OR table2.colum1 IS NULL and table2.colum2 IS NULL
```

tho this doenst seems to work. Could anyone help me a bit?

Data I have in table1:

```
---------
| 1 | 1 |
---------
| 2 | 2 |
---------
| 2 | 3 |
---------
```

data i have in table2:

```
---------
| 1 | 1 |
---------
| 2 | 3 |
---------
| 2 | 4 |
---------
```

expected outcome:

```
   t1      t2
-----------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
-----------------
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some ddl and sample data? What datatype(s) are you dealing with?

Comment: can you explain how you got to your expected outcome ?

Comment: @SeanLange I am dealing with strings

Comment: @GuidoG those are the rows which is present in his own table but not in the other table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic set-based approach is to use `UNION` and `EXCEPT`:

```
declare @t1 table (i1 int,i2 int)
insert into @t1(i1,i2) values
(1,1),
(2,2),
(2,3)

declare @t2 table (i1 int,i2 int)
insert into @t2(i1,i2) values
(1,1),
(2,3),
(2,4)

(select i1,i2 from @t1
except
select i1,i2 from @t2)
union all
(select i1,i2 from @t2
except
select i1,i2 from @t1)
```

Result:

```
i1          i2
----------- -----------
2           2
2           4
```

Comment: Thanks this solved it, could you add how I would get the differences for each table in a column besides the other columns? I updated my answer to see what i mean.

Comment: @wouterdejong - there's no obvious way (given the data so far) to match rows from each table to each other, given that these are rows of missing data. If this is purely a *presentational* matter, I'd suggest it be dealt with at your presentation layer. If there is a way to connect the data `2,2` from one table with the data `2,4` in the other, please explain it. It may also help, in this circumstance, to present more sample data and expected results, so that the relationships are clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT coalesce(table1.col1, table2.col1) as col1
   , coalesce(table1.col2, table2.col2) as col2
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 and table1.col2 = table2.col2
WHERE (table1.col1 IS NULL and table1.col2 IS NULL)
    OR (table2.col1 IS NULL and table2.col2 IS NULL)
```